# Net::Telnet, send yes or no

Tags: perl

I'm writing a program that use Net::Telnet, but when i use `$tel->cmd` , the equipment waits for yes or no to continue the cmd, how can i do that using Net::Telnet?

Comment: Looks like you specify the `prompt` argument to `cmd`, and when it returns, you use `$tel->cmd('yes');`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not expect the prompt to show up, use `print()` and `waitfor()` instead of `cmd()`.

For an example conversation:

```
testmachine# launch-fireworks
Are you sure? (yes/no/MAYBE) yes
Fireworks launched
testmachine#
```

Could be automated like:

```
$telnet->print('launch-fireworks');
$telnet->waitfor('Are you sure? (yes/no/MAYBE)');
$telnet->cmd('yes');
```

After `yes` we expect the prompt to show up, so we can use `cmd()` again.